# Inheritance of a non-const variable as const

Tags: c++, oop

I am defining a class of 3d floating point vectors of fixed norm 1. In order to do so, I am extending a class `vec3` of vectors without constraints. That's how I've done it:

```
class normed_vec3 : public vec3
{
  private:
    // unsafe constructor, doesn't check the invariant
    normed_vec3(float w0, float w1, float w2);

  public:
    // construct a normed vector from an ordinary one by normalizing it
    explicit normed_vec3(const vec3& w);

    // coordinates can only be returned as const, to preserve the invariant
    float x() const { return vec3::x; }
    float y() const { return vec3::y; }
    float z() const { return vec3::z; }
};
```

This works. It is slightly unpleasant as `vec3` has `x`, `y` and `z` as member variables (not sure if relevant: I'm importing `vec3` from glm, so I didn't write and don't want to change its interface), whereas `normed_vec3`'s public interface has them as functions, so the code is a bit inconsistent, because depending on the type, the code reads things like `v.x` or `v.x()`. It's not the end of the world, but it's a bit unsatisfying.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This is the typical beginner mistake of implementing `Square` by inheriting `Rectangle`. Your `normed_vec3` cannot both fulfill the requirements of a `vec` and also maintain its own invariants. You can't prevent someone from creating a `vec3&` to a `normed_vec3` and changing any of its members such that it would break the invariance of the `normed_vec3` (to be unit length). Your type shouldn't inherit from `vec3`. At least not publically.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux got it. Thanks!